# Unfortunately Google play store has stopped working on one plus x

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, oneplus-x

After updating my One Plus X to Android 6,
`unfortunately Google play store has stopped working` error pops-up
and I can't open Google play store.

I tried all the methods. Please help me.

Comment: What are `all the methods` ?

Answer (score 11):

Disable Google +... Settings>apps>Google + and then reboot

Comment: Onehundredandfourteenthousand times thanks! Although this issues seems to have nothing to do with Google+, disabling the app works. Though on Android 6.0.1 I had to reinstall Google+ becaus apparently, disabling a factory app deinstalls the app.

Comment: Worked wonderfully!

Comment: Really amazing it worked !

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me :-(